# Can't find notepad++ on my linux after installation

Tags: linux, wine

I installed notepad++ on my linux using wine. I ran it after installation and it worked fine. I want to keep using npp but I cannot find it anywhere in my files. It was installed in a virtual C drive created by wine. 
I can't seem to figure out how to open wine either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't "open" Wine per se: Wine creates entries on the Applications menu of your desktop environment.

Otherwise, you can use a terminal to cd to `~/.wine/drive_c/` and try to find Notepad++ there (probably it will be under Program Files/Notepad++). Then you can launch app using `wine exe_name.exe`.

Comment: sry for nagging but i have no idea how to get to ~/.wine/drive_c/. I could definitely find my way from there. Do you know how to find out where that directory is?

Comment: `~` means your home directory (try this out by typing `cd ~` in a terminal then hitting tab). Files/folders starting with `.` are hidden by default, so if you're navigating by the file manager you'll need to turn on 'show hidden files'. Or you can get there in a terminal just by typing `cd ~/.wine/drive_c/`.

Answer (score 1):

Wine is not a graphical application, therefore you cannot "open" it. You can access most of its settings via `winecfg` though.

What wine describes as it's virtual C: drive is set in this application, and is by default located at `~/.wine/drive_c`

Running applications in wine is often not the way to go though, especially when equivalent, or (often) better, native applications exist. There's a question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72106/what-can-i-use-as-a-notepad-alternative-in-linux-ubuntu).